# How to rewrite urls using ProxyHTMLURLMap?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy, regex, httpd.conf

My urls are in this form

```
/sites/site-name/Subpath-2/page-name.page
/sites/site-name/Subpath-3/Subpath-4/index.page
```

And this should be rewritten as `/sitename/subpath/pagename`  (the extention `.page` is removed)
also the subpath can have multiple folders ie (/sites/site-name/Subpath-2/..../page-name.page)

If we have a url ending with index.page then we must remove the index.page eg:
`/sites/site-name/...subpath.../index.page` should be `/sites/site-name/...subpath.../`

I have tried using back references in this way

```
ProxyHTMLURLMap "\/sites\/([A-Za-z-0-9]+|-)\/([A-Za-z-0-9]+|-)\/([A-Za-z-0-9]+|-)\.page$" "/$1/$2/$3" R
```

And for urls ending with index

```
ProxyHTMLURLMap "\/sites\/([A-Za-z-0-9]+|-)\/([A-Za-z-0-9]+|-)\/(index)\.page$" "/$1/$2/" R
```

**But I need to rewrite the URLs in such away that the subpaths can be many ie it should work for any urls which can have more that three subpaths**
it needs to work for `/sites/site-name/Subpath-3/Subpath-4/index.page`
/sites/site-name/Subpath-1/Subpath-2/Subpath-3/home.page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ProxyHTMLURLMap "\/sites((\/([A-Za-z-0-9]+|-))*)\/([A-Za-z-0-9]+|-)\.page$" "$1/$4" R
```

Breaking that apart:

- `((\/([A-Za-z-0-9]+|-))*)` is any number of path components - zero or more - following `/sites`. Each component begins with `/`. The whole string of all of the path components is stored in `$1`.
- At the end is `([A-Za-z-0-9]+|-)\.page$`, the file name ending in `.page`. Its result is stored in `$4`, because it starts with the 4th open parenthesis in the expression.

If you want to require at least one path component between `/sites` and the file name, instead of zero or more, you can change the `*` to a `+`.